# vi encryption: what algorithm has been used?

Tags: encryption, vi

I used an encrypted file to store my passwords for years. It has been encrypted using the `vi -x` command on Sun Solaris 10. I now tried to open the file on a linux box with both`vi -x` and `vi -x -cm=blowfish`. Sadly the file is completely messed up. My guess is that a different encryption algorithm has been used on Solaris. How can I find out which algorithm has been used and how can I open the file with a more recent version of vi?

I do know the correct password and I do know several words in the encrypted file.

P.S.: I do not have any access to a solaris 10 Machine anymore

Comment: You might have some "luck" browsing the Solaris source code at http://www.opensolaris.org. I did, a little, and it looks that vi, which uses ex code internally, uses libcrypt, which popen's the [crypt](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/cmd/crypt/crypt.c) command internally. That in turn, doesn't seem to use any "well known" algorithm. Be warned tough, I might be totally out of the ballpark here.

Comment: what are the first characters of the encrypted file?  For example, recent versions of vi show VimCrypt

Answer (score 0):

I think vi uses the crypt function.  This is a long shot, but if you have access to mcrypt, this should decode solaris crypt:

```
mcrypt  -a des --keymode pkdes --bare --noiv --decrypt filename
```

old unix style crypt

```
mcrypt  -a  enigma  --keymode  scrypt --bare --decrypt filename
```

Answer (score 0):

*/usr/bin/vi* (also linked from /usr/ucb/vi), */usr/xpg4/bin/vi*, and */usr/xpg6/bin/vi* on Solaris 10 (and such of those as were on all earlier versions of Solaris) all used crypt(1) (Enigma variant) encryption.

On Solaris 11 and later, *vi* is actually *vim*, and uses whatever encryption that version of vim supports, which is NOT compatible with crypt(1).

"Old" vi may still be on Solaris 11 as /usr/sunos/bin/vi, but does not have the -x option any more.

crypt(1) is also no longer on Solaris 11.

But one can easily scrounge the source (google for usr/src/cmd/crypt/crypt.c) and fix up whatever version one finds to compile ok.

And as a previous poster indicated, mcrypt can do the job too.

The latter is available for Macs via (at least) MacPorts ("port install mcrypt" although a trivial test of running mcrypt there didn't work for me), for CentOS via "yum install mcrypt", for Ubuntu via "apt install mcrypt"; cygwin also has an mcrypt package.

For any other OS or distro, you're on your own; I don't have everything.